# What is the user agent used by Whatsapp to crawl sites?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

I'm working on a site doing some SEO tweaking and I've noticed that Whatsapp takes whatever "og:image" is listed last. For some odd reason, when I list the small image for whatsapp, my twitter card picks that one too, instead of the one I gave specifically for Twitter.

So I'm considering just listing the "og:images" excluding the one for Whatsapp, except when the user agent is WhatsApp's.

With that in mind, I'd like to know what is the user agent given by WhatsApp's crawler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

whatsapp user-agent : `WhatsApp/2.19.81 A`

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp uses different user-agents depending on the version you use.... What I did to check for whatsapp was to compare the first 8 characters of `user-agent` string to `WhatsApp` as al of them start with WhatsApp in my observation