# Which user-agenct/bot used by whatsApp to crawl websites for link preview

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, whatsapp, prerender

Which user-agenct/bot used by whatsApp to crawl websites for link preview ,
I am setting-up pre-render for my react site using prerender.io there i have to mention user-agent bots like faceBot and GoogleBot
Now i want to handle pre-rendering for whatsApp but i do not whatsApp crawler (user-agent)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe this will help, haven't tested my self [what-is-the-user-agent-used-by-whatsapp-to-crawl-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795103/what-is-the-user-agent-used-by-whatsapp-to-crawl-sites)

Answer (score 0):

As of current date it is `WhatsApp/2.23.4.79 A`. That's what I'm getting.